# After selecting a virtual ListView item programmatically, how can I make Shift+Click work correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `ListView` with `VirtualMode = true` and am trying to change the selected item programmatically with:

```
listView1.SelectedIndices.Clear();
listView1.SelectedIndices.Add(i);
```

This works, but I have noticed that following the change, Shift+Click on the ListView selects a range starting from the *previously clicked* item rather than the currently selected one.  How can I make it behave in the normal way, selecting a range from the currently selected item?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but it turns out that `SelectedIndices.Add()` doesn't behave well in virtual mode.  Setting `Selected = True` on the item works correctly with Shift+Click:

```
listView1.SelectedIndices.Clear();
listView1.Items[i].Selected = true
```

Perhaps someone can clarify this or post a better answer.